# Table in td HTML Таблица в таблице

Tags: php, html, css, html5

Если в абзаце слишком длинный текст то размеры нарушаются

```css
<style>
    table{
        width:100%;
        margin:10px 0 20px 0;
    }
    table,tr,td{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    p{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        padding:5px;
        font-size: auto;
        text-align:center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        min-height:150px;

        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
     <p> </p>
   </td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложили б хотя бы html разметку

Comment: Зачем вам таблица в таблице? Почему нельзя обойтись одной?

Comment: потому что я с postgresql тащу данные в таблицу

Comment: подробнее, пожалуйста. @bald

Answer (score 1):

Таблица в таблице делается так:

```css
<style>
    table{
        width:100%;
        margin:10px 0 20px 0;
    }
    table,tr,td{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        text-align:center;
    }
    td {
        padding:10px
    }
</style>
```

```html
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
   
   <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
         adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet 
         dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat. Ut wisis enim ad minim veniam, quis 
         nostrud exerci tution ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
         commodo consequat.
        </td>

    <td width="150" style="">
    
     <table width="100%">
      <tr><td>Lorem</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Ipsum</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Dolor</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Sit</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Amet</td></tr>
     </table>
     
    </td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
         adipiscing elit, sed diem nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet 
         dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat. Ut wisis enim ad minim veniam, quis 
         nostrud exerci tution ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea 
         commodo consequat.</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```